# What’s the difference between abide by law and abide by the law? What does the article the’ before the word law represent?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, articles, nouns, uncountable-nouns

Is the phrase abide by law is correct? How to use articles after prepositions like by and in ?

Answer (score 3):

First, the fact that "law" appears after the word "by" doesn't make a difference here, so the following focuses just on whether the definite article is used. ("Abide by" is a phrasal verb, meaning "obey".)

I think "the law" means all established, existing law in some context, for example, all the laws of a nation, or all the laws applying to international trade. If "law" is followed by the preposition "of", it will probably use a definite article, for example, "the law of that country", since that is a definite use.

"Law" without an article means the principle of law in general, without referring to particular, existing laws. However, to abide by law (in general) implies abiding by particular laws, so it's a subtle difference that may not make any difference in a given usage.

I found one example of the use of both forms in one sentence:
"When we ask the Negro to **abide by the law**, let us also declare that the white man does not **abide by law** in the ghettos."
(Martin Luther King Jr. "The Lost Massey Lectures: Recovered Classics from Five Great Thinkers" (found at Google books).

This ngram shows that "abide by the law" is eighteen times more common than "abide by law":
[Google ngram abide by the law, abide by law](https://tinyurl.com/y9jmsc33)

Comment: I would say "by" is a preposition rather than a particle here, but that is a less important technicality here.

Comment: @EddieKal Yes, you're right. I made a correction.